# Getting SqlException for a foreign key when building database on init

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Im using Entity Framework Core and need to specify which Product the ProductGraphic entity belongs to, but I get this exception:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException occurred   HResult=0x80131904
>   Message=Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   'FK_ShopProductGraphic_ShopProduct_ProductId' on table
>   'ShopProductGraphic' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths.
>   Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other
>   FOREIGN KEY constraints. . . .

If I set the ProductId type to nullable the init of the database works, but the list of ProductGraphic's in Product is always empty.

**ProductGraphic.cs**:

```
[Table("ShopProductGraphic")]
public class ProductGraphic : Base
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int GraphicId { get; set; }
    public virtual Graphic Graphic { get; set; }
}
```

**Product.cs:**

```
[Table("ShopProduct")]
public class Product : BaseShop
{
    public bool Active { get; set; } = true;
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public int CultureId { get; set; } = -1;
    public List<ProductInfo> InfoItems { get; set; } = new List<ProductInfo>();
    public List<ProductGraphic> GraphicItems { get; set; }
}
```

**Base.cs**:

```
public abstract class Base
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Guid UId { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
}
```

ShopBase is currently just an empty abstract class that inherits Base

Comment: Please post the snapshots of Base and BaseShop class too. You are missing Product Reference in ProductGraphics class and ProductId in Product class. Those maybe defined in Base or BaseShop classes, that's why you should post the snapshots of Base, BaseShop classes too.

Comment: I've updated the question with info about the base classes, thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 1):

Add Product Reference in ProductGraphic class like you have done for Graphic,

```
[Table("ShopProductGraphic")]
public class ProductGraphic : Base
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int GraphicId { get; set; }
    public virtual Graphic Graphic { get; set; }
    public virtual Product Product {get; set;}
}
```